# How to promote a blog?

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, game-theory, applied-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

Math behind might be interesting.

Quite recent bloggingg activity might have interesting math model.
The point is that bloggers compete for subscribers and at the same time
cooperate gaining subscribers from partner's blogs.  Question is about existence of something like [J.Nash's equilibrium strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium) which should balance competition/cooperation.

---

**Setup:**

There are inet blogs, each blog has $K_i$ subscribers (=readers).

**"Competition:"** Blog earns $K_i/( \sum K_i )$  money.
So: more subscribers blog has (relatively to other blogs) - more it earns.
Each blogger's goal is to earn more money.

**"Cooperation:"**
Assume the following cooperation behaviour:   10 blogs make agreement and each of them recommend to its subscribers  to subscribe to that 10 blogs. Assume some small percent e.g. 1% of subscribers follow that recommendation, so  $.01*(K_2+K_3+...K_{10}) $  subscribers comes to blog $1$ from blogs 2,3,...10, and
$.01*(K_1+K_3+...K_{10})$ comes to blog 2 from blogs 1,3,4...10 and so on.

**Question:** What should be optimal choice of 9 partners for your blog, if you want to maximize your profit ? Assume you can (but not obliged) offer cooperation to any 9 blogs and they have right to accept / not accept your offer.

What is the point here:
if you are the largest subscriber holder - probably you should NOT cooperate with anybody since it will decrease your relative advantage,
on the other hand smaller bloggers will cooperate between themselves and if you do nothing sooner or later they will overcome you.
That is why you probably should also act.

We might assume that cooperation process happens at the end of each day.
And money are paid at the end of each day.
So there is time evolution. Probably at the end we will come to uniform distribution of subscribers between blogs.
But the question what are optimal choices at each time step.

---

It might be model should include more assumptions to be more interesting/realistic. We should take into account that if two blogs have the same audience, then self-advertising will not help.

**Question:**  Any improvements to the setup ?

Comment: Sounds like prisoners dilemma

Comment: The zero-sum assumption seems unrealistic, since good content can grow the reader pool, and bad content can shrink it.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins let us forget about quality of content

Comment: Indeed. I would like to think that good content should always outweigh attempts at self-aggrandisement by orders of magnitude. Look out Tao's or Baez's blogs.

Comment: So you need "content" in your setup or its not a maths blog!

Comment: @JamesSmith the question is about model which is described it captures real life to certain extent

Comment: You haven't defined a game yet. In a game, there is a set of players (defined), a set of actions (more or less defined -- I guess it is the choice of which other players to connect to), and a utility function for each player mapping the actions to a utility. This is not defined -- you define utility in terms of $\{K_i\}$ but you don't define how $K_i$ depends on the actions of the players. Once you define this, the game is finite so by Nash it will have a mixed strategy equilibrium (meaning the choices of whom to connect to may be randomized).

Comment: Here is a fleshed-out utility function. Each player has a given static "content score" $C_i$. Now draw a player graph where vertex $i$ has an edge to each of its $10$ chosen neighbors with weights $0.01\alpha$, an edge back to itself with weight $0.9\alpha$, and an additional edge to every $i$ with weight $(1-\alpha)C_i / \sum_j C_j$. Now define $K_i$ to be the stationary probability placed on $i$ by a random walk on this graph where edge weights are transition probabilities. (This is a version of pagerank where $\alpha$ is an exploration parameter.) Now $i$'s utility is $K_i$ .

Comment: @usul Sorry. why "you don't define how Ki depends on the actions of the players" ? That is defined in "cooperation" section. You choose "partner blogs" everyday and 1% of partners subscribers come to you. So there is very clear dependence.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov, it's not clear to me: what is $K_i$ as a function of the decisions of the players? For instance, say there are 20 blogs and all 20 of them choose to link to $1,\dots,10$. What are $K_1,\dots,K_{20}$?

Comment: @usul you can only partner with 9 blogs one day. So if we have 20 blogs there will be only TWO parnerships each include 10 blogs. For each partnerships Ki will increase in the way described in the text